# ti.strorekit shows different price in "Confirm your in-app purchase" dialog

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, titanium

Developing in-app purchase for a titanium app. Used app.js from the ti.storekit module for reference.I could successfully purchase product but "Confirm Your In-App Purchase" dialog always shows me price with Rs 50 extra.Following the code in app.js line by line. For 30 days subscription, I've selected Tier 5 ($4.99 & Rs 300). Before calling Storekit.purchse(product), I get product.formattedPrice as Rs 300, but on confirmation dialog its Rs 350. I am confused why it is adding Rs 50 extra. It would be nice if anybody could help. Thanks in advance. Couldn't post screenshot due to less reputation :(

code-

```
var Storekit= require('ti.storekit');

requestProducts('oneMonthSubscription', function (product) {
var buySingleItem = Ti.UI.createButton({
title:'Buy ' + product.title + ', ' + product.formattedPrice,
top:70, left:5, right:5, height:40
});
buySingleItem.addEventListener('click', function () {
purchaseProduct(product);
});
win.add(buySingleItem);     
});

function purchaseProduct(product)
{
Storekit.purchase(product);
}
```

Comment: Apple just made a few adjustments to some currency tiers in the past couple of days. Could it be that?

Comment: But I don't understand, when I print formattedPrice of product why it is showing me 300. As well as in iTunes in manage in-app purchases, it is showing old pricing matrix yet. Its bit confusing :(